# What's the difference between Inject and Provider in JSR-330

Tags: java, spring, guice, ioc-container, jsr330

all

I don't know what's the difference between Inject and Provider in JSR-330.
I am using google guice, and everyday using `@Inject`, and I know in JSR-330, it has `Provider<T>`.

My question is

1. what's the meaning of `Provider<T>` ?
2. when can when user `Provider<T>` ?
3. what's the difference with `@Inject` ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Everything is already explained into the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/inject/Provider.html), I quote:

> **Compared to injecting `T` directly** *(implicitly using `@Inject` only)*, injecting `Provider<T>` enables:
>
> 1. retrieving multiple instances.
> 2. lazy or optional retrieval of an instance.
> 3. breaking circular dependencies.
> 4. abstracting scope so you can look up an instance in a smaller scope from an instance in a containing scope.

**Example for #1:**

Here you get several instances of `Seat` from the same provider so it is used as a factory.

```
class Car {
    @Inject 
    Car(Provider<Seat> seatProvider) {
        Seat driver = seatProvider.get();
        Seat passenger = seatProvider.get();
        ...
    }
}
```

**Example for #2:**

Here you use a provider to avoid creating directly the instance of the class `MyClassLongToCreate` as we know that it is a slow operation, so we will get it lazily thanks to the `get` method only when it is needed.

```
class MyClass {
    @Inject
    private Provider<MyClassLongToCreate> lazy;
    ...
}
```

**Example for #3:**

Here is a circular dependency that cannot be solved easily by the container such that some containers could just throw an exception as they don't know how to solve it by their own.

```
class C1 {
    private final C2 c2;
    @Inject
    C1(C2 c2) {
        this.c2 = c2;
        ...
    }
}

class C2 {
    private final C1 c1;
    @Inject
    C2(C1 c1) {
        this.c1 = c1;
        ...
    }
}
```

To fix it we use a `Provider` on at least one of the constructors to break the circular dependency as next:

```
class C1 {
    private final Provider<C2> c2;
    @Inject
    C1(Provider<C2> c2) {
        this.c2 = c2;
        ...
    }
}
```

This will allow the container to fully create an instance of `C1` first (as we don't actually need to create an instance of `C2` to inject a provider of `C2`) once done the container will be able to create an instance of `C2` from this instance of `C1`.

**Example for #4:**

Here you have a class `C2` that is scoped to the session which depends on `C1` that itslef scoped to the request, we use a provider to allow us to get the instance of `C1` corresponding to the current request as it will change from one request to another.

```
@RequestScoped
public class C1 {
    ...  
}

@SessionScoped
public class C2 {
    @Inject
    private Provider<C1> provider;
    ...
    public void doSomething() {
        // Get the instance corresponding to the current request
        C1 c1 = provider.get();
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: #2 - slow is not the only reason, you may also have a need for the object injected to be created when actually needed instead of at initial injection time.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen if by #2, you mean "Example for #2" it is only an example to show the idea nothing more. What you described is already mentioned in my answer it is the "optional retrieval"

Comment: That is in the quote only.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen the quote is the answer, the rest only illustrates it